# Is there a way to programmatically create many buckets rather than hardcoding in SSMS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a field whose values can range anywhere from 0-60 (including decimals). I need to bucket these records based on these values in increments of 1 (e.g. 0-1, 1-2, 2-3, and so on until 59-60). Is there a way to bucket them without having to do a gigantic case statement all the way to 60 like this?

```
CASE
    WHEN FieldOfValues > 0 AND FieldOfValues <= 1 THEN '0-1'
    WHEN FieldOfValues > 1 AND FieldOfValues <= 2 THEN '1-2'
    ...
END
```

EDIT 1: Fixed typos; added slight clarifications

Comment: You can use the `PIVOT` syntax. It may be more concise than `CASE`.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov `PIVOT`/`UNPIOVT` still requires explicit column listings - it offers few advantages over ISO-standard syntax.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://sqlsunday.com/2014/09/14/histogram-in-t-sql/

Comment: Looking at your case statement, >0 AND <=1 is just 1, >1 AND <=2 is just 2... why do you need a `case` statement at all - are you dealing with decimals?

Comment: `0-2` ? Typo error ?

Comment: what is the data type for `FieldOfValues ` ?

Comment: Yes, ```0-2``` was a typo. The data type is numeric @Squirrel

Comment: The values can be decimals @Stu

Comment: Are your bucket boundaries correct? You use `[LowerBound] < [FieldOfValues] <= [UpperBound]`, while in many general scenarios, `[LowerBound] <= [FieldOfValues] < [UpperBound]` is used. (Stated differently: normally, the lowerbound is inclusive and the upperbound is exclusive.) Is your logic intentionally different in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating buckets that potentially might not have values in them, I went this route instead:

```
IIF(FieldOfValues < 60,
    CONCAT(
        FLOOR(FieldOfValues)
        ,'-'
        ,FLOOR(FieldOfValues) + 1
    )
    ,'60+'
) WeightBucket
```

Comment: You can get 60-61 and also 60+, which is weird. You should choose 60-61 and 61+ or 59-60 and 60+.

Comment: This is a nice answer. I used to have a solution like this in my answer as well, but I used `FLOOR` for the lowerbound and `CEILING` for the upperbound. That would result in buckets like `24-24` for value `24`, which was incorrect. Your solution is much better. Note that if you want to regard the OP's divergent inclusive/exclusive boundary logic, you can replace `FLOOR(...)` and `FLOOR(...) + 1` with `CEILING(...) - 1` and `CEILING(...)` respectively. If not, it might be useful to use `<` instead of `<=` in your `IIF` check to avoid bucket `60-61` for value `60`, as @AntoninLejsek mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @AntonínLejsek. I've edited the answer to change ```<=``` to ```<```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a recursive CTE to your query to create a table of values, which can serve as the basis for your number ranges (or "buckets" as you call them). In your query, you can join the CTE with your data table to determine the correct bucket in which your `FieldOfValues` value belongs.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT 1 AS Val
UNION ALL
  SELECT Val + 1
  FROM CTE
  WHERE Val < 60
)
SELECT
  FieldOfValues,
  CAST(CTE.Val - 1 AS VARCHAR) + '-' + CAST(CTE.Val AS VARCHAR) AS Bucket
FROM
  [YourTable]
  INNER JOIN CTE ON FieldOfValues <= CTE.Val AND FieldOfValues > CTE.Val - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

So would the following suggestion work for you?

A table of ranges to permanently store your divisions and required value(s)

You can then just select from it or join to it:

```
create table Ranges (id int identity(1,1) primary key, LowerBound decimal(9,5), UpperBound decimal(9,5), Value varchar(5))

insert into Ranges (LowerBound, UpperBound, [Value]) values
(0,1,'0-1'),
(1,2,'1-2'),
(2,3,'2-3'),
(3,4,'3-4'),
(4,5,'4-5')
... etc
declare @Fieldvalue decimal(9,5)=3.62

select [value]
from ranges
where @Fieldvalue>LowerBound and @Fieldvalue<=UpperBound
```